# Ansible Variable above hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Ansible Variable above hosts

hello its posible to create a variable for multi hosts like this?

```
  vars:
    some_vars: "./Prometheus/roles/" # <---- THIS Variable?
- hosts: lxd1
  vars_files:
    - Prometheus/vars/grafana_vars.yml
  become: true
  roles:
    - '{{ some_vars }}Stouts.grafana'   <--- var usage
- hosts: lxd1
  vars_files:
    - Prometheus/vars/exporters_common_vars.yml
  become: true
  roles:
    - './Prometheus/roles/ansible-prometheus-exporters-common'
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you want to do this?  Perhaps we can provide an alternative that may work?

Comment: playbook is for specific client and other parts like roles vars and other are submodules so path to file can change and i dont wanna make 30-40 change in path on playbook to run playbook for specific client and second problem jenkins run this playbook

Answer (score 2):

No that is not valid syntax in a playbook.  There is no way within a playbook to include vars that will apply for all plays.

If you want variables applied to multiple plays, and so multiple hosts hosts define them in your inventory or group_vars.

You could also pass variables from the command line, if you need variables to apply to many plays using the `-e` option.

Comment: Or in the vars directory alongside the play.  By default,  vars/main.yml will be included.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in @Zoredache post I would use group_vars in order to define a group to apply vars to all host.

In order to do that I would use a following inventory file :

```
[dev-servers]                       # inventory for dev servers
dev1.example.com
dev2.example.com

[production-servers]                # inventory for production servers
prod1.example.com
prod2.example.com

[allvars:children]                  # group vars to apply for all hosts
dev-servers
production-servers

[productionvars:children]           # group vars to apply for only production
production-servers

[devvars:children]                  # group vars to apply for only dev
dev-servers
```

Then you will have to create a dedicate `group_vars file` for `allvars group`, please find here an example of directory layout :

```
inventory_host                       # inventory file

group_vars/
   allvars.yml             # here we assign variables to all hosts
   productionvars.yml      # here we assign variables to only prod hosts
   devvars.yml             # here we assign variables to only dev hosts
```